# Designer.Cs files not registering update to namespace

Tags: c#, web-config, visual-studio-2012

I am having a problem with visual studios premium 2012.

Recently, I changed the namespace of a button control, which inherits from `Linkbutton`. Code looks like this:

```
//namespace MyOldNameSpace
namespace MyNewNameSpace
{
    public class myButton : LinkButton
    {
        //some stuff here
    }
}
```

I updated my all references to this code to match this change. **However...**

The designer.cs files refuse to generate the buttons with the newly updated namespace. For instance, the functions look like this in my designer.cs files:

```
protected global::MyOldNameSpace.myButton myButton1
```

In order to make everything compile and work, I have to go into the code and update the Namespace in the designer.cs files. I am having no functionality issues. Also, I changed my web.config to match the new changes.

I have tried the following:

- Closing and re-opening visual studios
- Going into ~/../appdata/ and removing some files [found this solution on a blog]

But none of this has worked.

Thanks in advance

EDIT some changes that I made:

in web.config

```
<add tagPrefix="abc" namespace="MyNewNameSpace" assembly="MyNewNameSpace"
```

in the .aspx page

```
<abc:myButton runat="server" onclick=...etc...>
```

Comment: List all the parts you did change (web.config, .aspx) to avoid wasting time here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman edited original post

Comment: Is this a desktop app?  Why would there be a web-config?  If it is a web app have you tried deleting the contents of designer files, making a change to the ASP code, and saving them again?  Have you tried find replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actions are:

1. You change the namespace inside the class definition
2. You update the web.config with the new namespace

What you expect is:

1. Visual Studio will update the aspx.designer.cs file with the new namespace

How it really works:

**Updates to the designer.cs are triggered by changes in the .aspx file.**

There are <strike>2</strike> **3** possible scenarios to solve the problem:

1. You have to ***Cut the control tag from the .aspx page => Save the .aspx page => Paste the control tag back inside the .aspx page => Save the .aspx page***
2. or you **manually modify the line by replacing the namespace**:

   ```
   protected global::MyOldNameSpace.myButton mButton;//old line
   protected global::MyNewNameSpace.myButton mButton;//new line
   ```

   **[EDIT]**
3. or you **switch the .aspx from Source to Design => Save => Rebuild => Switch to Source**

I'd say the option number three is the preferred workaround.

Comment: Thanks. The second scenario is what I ended up doing. I found out that my error was related to something in Mercurial

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you want to try the third workaround, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a regular class assembly VS 2013. I right clicked on the project node, then selected 'Properties'. I selected the 'Application' section and then changed the 'Default namespace' to my new value. Recompiled. Problem solved. 
IMO we shouldn't have to do that. We should be able to make changes to the source code and expect them to be carried through without changing configuration data.